# Cakephp always returning 404 on Amazon EC2

Tags: cakephp, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to setup cakephp on an Amazon instance (Ubuntu) ..
However all requests made to the application is returning 404 ..

What is it that am doing wrong ??

Regards
Abhishek jain

Comment: Do you get Cake's 404 page or the webserver's or Amazon's? Did you try to run the Cake app in a local environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1. Check LAMP is configured `mod_rewrite` using test file with `<?php phpinfo();`
2. Is htaccess file is allowed to override rewrite settings `AllowOverride=All`. check `httpd.conf`.
3. Check apache's DocumentRoot is set the webroot of your cake application.

Comment: checked for first 2 steps and they seemed right .. however am not sure what is it that i need to check for the 3rd point .. my application is in a subfolder under the webroot folder .. as .. /var/www/cakeapp ..

Answer (score 0):

I have configured Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type on Amazon EC2 and configuring the Apache Mysql & PHP5 on the same after finishing the setup i configured CakePHP and getting 404 error when i was trying to access any page then i got a solution on the same which i am going to share with you ..

Hope it will work for you..

**Enabling mod_rewrite on Ubuntu**

let's make sure you have actually enabled mod_rewrite. At your terminal prompt, enter the following:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Easy. Did it work? if so great! If not, try these next couple of steps. Again in the terminal, open up the following file with:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

OR

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

And now change the AllowOverride value to "All" along with others. I have included what the file should now look like for a default installation.

Restart Apache and you're done:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Below is a sample file with the after mentioned changes.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />                                                 
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All                                 
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All                                 
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this will work for you...